# Download json file from REST API

Tags: rest, powershell, azure-devops

I am trying to export a build pipeline from Azure DevOps using the REST API provided by them. I am able to download json file using below sample url which contains the build definition in json format.

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=5.0-preview.7
```

But when i try to download using powershell i get HTML file with html tags. But i need just the Json file which will be actual Build definition file to be downloaded.
Below is my powershell code . I also tried using  -ContentType "application/json" but it didn't resolve it.

```
$strURL = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=5.0-preview.7"
$filePath="C:\Pipeline_export"
$fileName=$filePath+"\build.json"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $strURL  -OutFile $fileName
```

Comment: What contains the HTML? how do you authorize against ADO?

Comment: What does `Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $strURL` return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the html is propably an error-page saying you didn't authorize correctly.

I use the following code for rest-api requests:

```
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "",$connectionToken)))
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $finalUrl -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

`$finalUrl` is the url of the resource, `$connectionToken` is my PersonalAccessToken

Comment: Should add how to generate the token. Personally I can use `credential` with `$cred = Get-Credential` then export it with `export-clixml` and import it with `import-clixml` when I need it, but there's many ways to generate tokens / credentials for apis.

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, you may lost authorized token in your code. So that it does not work using -ContentType "application/json".

On the other hand, we can also use another way to get code authorized: just enable **Allow scripts to access the OAuth token** and the script could access the OAuth token through the **System.AccessToken** variable.

Here is the completely code that can get the Json file correctly which modified on the basis of your code(with System.AccessToken not PAT):

```
 $strURL = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionid}?api-version=5.0-preview.7"
 $filePath="D:\"
 $fileName=$filePath+"\build.json"
 $pipeline =Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $strURL -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"} -Method GET -OutFile $fileName
```

Before download the Json file locally, you can use

```
Write-Host "Pipeline = $($pipeline | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
```

to check whether the output in PowerShell Script logs is what you want.